# xtdpdml: how to draw interaction plots

Tags: panel, stata

I have one IV, one DV, one moderator, and two control variables.

The panel data is strongly balanced with 5 years.

Is there any way to draw an interaction plot of the xtdpdml results?

I've tried the usual methods, (iv: independent variable with values from 1 to 6; mo: moderator with values from 1 to 6)

```
egen iv = rowmean (q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6)
egen dv = rowmean (qd1 qd2 qd3 qd4 qd5 qd6)
egen mo = rpwmean (qm1 qm2 qm3 qm4 qm5 qm6)
egen im = iv * dv

xtdpdml dv, inv(gender birthyear) pre(iv mo im) fiml
 
summarize mo

global moa = round(r(mean) + r(sd),0.1)

global mo = round(r(mean),0.1)

global mob = round(r(mean) - r(sd),0.1)

margins, at(iv=(1(1)6) mo=($moa $mo $mob))
```

and the error messages showed up saying 'iv ambiguous abbreviation.'

Comment: Editing the question to clarify is a really good idea. Editing the question and changing names arbitrarily is not so helpful and makes my answer more difficult to understand. If this were your real code it would fail at trying to use `rpwmean()` which is a typo for `rowmean()`. That's easy, but I can't help much beyond that. `xtdpdml` is community-contributed but I've never used it. `margins` is official code, but I am not fluent in it.

Comment: The major issue appears to be nothing to do with rounding, but why `margins` doesn't understand `iv`. Do you have other variables whose names start with `iv`? Ideally, you need to show us a minimal reproducible example, which is hard here, but without it this question may not get a good answer.

Comment: 1) Right. I found "You should not try to do most post-estimation commands with the highlights version (e.g. predict, margins)
because necessary information may not be stored in the file; use the full version instead." from Williams, R., Allison, P. D., & Moral-Benito, E. (2018). Linear dynamic panel-data estimation using maximum likelihood and structural equation modeling. The Stata Journal, 18(2), 293-326. However, I have no idea what this 'full version' means. 
2) No. I have no other variables starting with iv.

Comment: Me neither without reading a long paper and trying to use the command. Perhaps approach the first author directly by email.

Comment: I'll add comment if there's any update. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT *This answer was in response to a previous version of the question using quite different variable names. It addresses only a side-issue, how to present numeric results rounded to a desired number of decimal places.*

Your code doesn't mention `pnv` so it is hard to comment.

I see what you want to do, but that is an awkward way to do it, and fallible. The problem is that Stata works in binary and can only hold a few of the decimal fractions 0.01(0.01)0.99 exactly, specifically 0.25 0.50 0.75. That's 3 out of 99; the rest must be held as approximations. Other Stata code means that you won't always see the approximations, but it's not guaranteed. I would try this, which makes the rounding into the formatting question it really is:

```
summarize sns
local snsa : di %2.1f r(mean) + r(sd)
local sns: di %2.1f r(mean) 
local snsb: di %2.1f r(mean) - r(sd)

margins, at(priv=(0(1)6) sns=(`snsa' `sns' `snsb'))
```

I can't rule out the real problem being in some other part of the code.

Comment: I edited the question including xtdpdml codes. Thanks for your help! I wrongly thought rounding would not cause any problems. But I still got the same error.